# R Drop rows where all columns beginning with a string have NAs

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have the following DataFrame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  "DateValue" = c("2016-07-01", "2016-07-02", "2016-07-03", "2016-07-04", "2016-07-05", "2016-07-06","2016-07-07"),  
  "Age1" = c(rep(NA, 2), seq(14,18,2), NA, NA), 
  "Age2" = c(rep(NA, 2), seq(14,22,2)) 
)
```

I am trying to delete all rows that contain NAs in all columns that begin with the string "Age". However, to not delete the rows where even one of the "age" column has a non missing value. The output I am aiming for is the following:

```
> df
    DateValue  Age1 Age2
  1 2016-07-03   14   14
  2 2016-07-04   16   16
  3 2016-07-05   18   18
  4 2016-07-06   NA   20
  5 2016-07-07   NA   22
```

I am trying the below R script to achieve the same but the NAs don't drop:

```
df <- df[!(is.na(grep("^Age", names(df)))), ]
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` to create a logical vector and subset the rows based on that

```
df[rowSums(!is.na(df[grep("^Age", names(df))])) > 0, ]
```

Comment: This drops even the last two rows that have a value for one of the "Age" columns.